# Error to use variables with nodejs, express and EJS - Not defined

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to use EJS. I call **response.render('agent.html', {name: 'aaaa'});**, and in HTML script I try access **<%= this.name %>**, but I have an error log saying **ReferenceError: aaaa is not defined**. Can you help me guys? Ty

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the html template is trying to access the aaa property on 'this' and it doesn't exist.  Instead in your html try: **<%= name %>**